# Split vertical columns in half

Tags: two-column

I want this
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
1
\vfill\null 
\columnbreak

2
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what you mean with " split each column into two`? What is in column? Do you like to have drawn red lines in the sketch? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I want to split column 1, by 2 horizontally (like this 1-3) @Zarko

Comment: your comment is not helpful. What should indicate that column is split?

Comment: I added a new image @Zarko

Comment: If you want the lines around given text, you can use `\columnseprule` to draw a line between columns, and `\noindent\rule[2pt]{\dimexpr \columnwidth+0.5\columnsep}{0.4pt}\hspace{-0.5\columnsep}` to connect (on the left).  If you want the text to flow between given sized rectangles, you can use the flowfram package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reproduce your image. But I'm not sure if this is useful (context of this is not clear to me)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

{
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
1
\vspace{4\baselineskip}

\noindent\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth+0.5\columnsep}{2pt}

3

\vspace{5\baselineskip}
\null
\columnbreak
2

\vspace{6\baselineskip}

\hspace{-2\columnsep}\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth+0.5\columnsep}{2pt}

4

\end{multicols}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I guess that you looking for the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand\Lrule{\par\noindent\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth+0.5\columnsep}{2pt}\par}
\newcommand\Rrule{\par\noindent\hspace{-0.5\columnsep}%
                               \rule{\dimexpr\linewidth+0.5\columnsep}{2pt}\par}

\begin{document}

{
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\Lrule
\lipsum[11]
\columnbreak

\lipsum[2]
\Rrule
\lipsum[22]
\end{multicols}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have been waiting for the Original Poster's interpretation of the right meaning. And nothing happened. :-(